# image src swap stopped working (jquery WP)

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I am having a new issue where a gallery stopped working. I know there are questions regarding attr('src'), I think this is unrelated as it was working fine for at least 2 years.

**Background**

I built a website back in 2013 that includes an image gallery that runs on jquery (1.8) - the site itself is Wordpress.

We handed the site off to the client and they were to manage updates etc. Needless to say they were bad with keeping WP up to date and a few weeks back they updated from 3.x to the current version. There were a few minor hiccups but all was fixed - or so we thought. Last week they noticed the gallery was not working. I know BEYOND A SHADOW OF A DOUBT that this was working fine about a year ago - I moved hosts for them, but now the image swapping does not work using jquery (see code below). Admittedly I have not been using jquery or WP that much over the last 18 months, but from what I can tell the jquery code is fine. On a wim, I swapped out WP 1.8 to WP 2.X and it still does not work. My gut is telling the WP update was the issue, but I am not sure why.

I am not sure if this is a WP issue maybe a script included (not an expert).

I do load all of the images into the browser so they are preloaded for the swap.

The console is not throwing any errors at all.

**How it works**

I load two image versions a thumb and the full size image. I hide the image using css on load. When the user clicks on the thumb I use the image's WP id to tie the two together (by making it part of the DOM id). On click, the wp id is passed to a function which takes all of the full size image details and then refreshes the main gallery.

**TLDR**

The following code used to swap out images on a gallery, the user updated WP a week or so back and they noticed it stopped working. I am not sure if the WP update is the issue, as all other parts of the script work fine.

```
//main js object
var ae = {
    switch_photo:function(pid) // method called from jq events
    {
        // pid - is the wp id that is shared between the gallery images and the thumbnails

                // is this a video or image gallery? (video galleries still work fine)
                var gal_type = $("#gallery-main-thumbs").data("galt");

                if(gal_type == "image")
                {

                    // there are two versions of each image loaded, the thumbnail and the full sized 
                    // full sized images are loaded then hidden with css so the image is available to be swapped.
                    // both images have id's that include the wp post id (the pid argument) - taht is how they are kept together
                    //  the var declarations below use this shared wp-id to get the attributes from the full sized image
                    var alt = $("#display_"+pid).attr("alt");
                    var bgcolor  = "#fff";
                    var src = $("#display_"+pid).attr("src");
                    var w = $("#display_"+pid).attr("width");
                    var h = $("#display_"+pid).attr("height");

                    // if the image is portrait set the bg to black for appearence's sake
                    if (parseInt(w) <= 670)
                    {
                        bgcolor = "#000";
                    }

                // shows the src url of the full sized  which is valid.
                console.log(src)

                // switch the bg color based upon image dimensions
                $("#gallery-focus").css("background-color", bgcolor);

                //swap out the main image - everything works except the src.
                $("#main-photo").attr("src", src);
                $("#main-photo").attr("width", w);
                $("#main-photo").attr("height", h);

                }
                else
                {
                    //video galleries - working fine.
                    var alt = $("#image_"+pid).children("img").attr("alt");
                    $("#gallery-focus").html($("#embed_"+pid).html());
                }

                $("#main-caption").text(alt);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue... the wp update by default was adding a srcset attribute for responsive images to the wp image tag. I disabled this in my functions as such (site is non responsive built in late '12 early '13):

```
function disable_srcset( $sources ) {
return false;
}
add_filter( 'wp_calculate_image_srcset', 'disable_srcset' );
```

This solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

If this is the real code that you are using, first add `;` after `console.log(src)`, secondly you have `alt` defined twice. Put `var alt;` outside of if condition, and then just set it as `alt = $("#display_"+pid).attr("alt");` in the if, and `alt = $("#image_"+pid).children("img").attr("alt");` in the else statement. The same is with `bgcolor`. And also you're missing semicolon at the end of your object definition `ae = {...};`.

```
var ae = {
    // method called from jq events
    switch_photo: function(pid) {
        // pid - is the wp id that is shared between the gallery images and the thumbnails

        // is this a video or image gallery? (video galleries still work fine)
        var gal_type = $("#gallery-main-thumbs").data("galt");
        var alt, bgcolor;

        if(gal_type == "image") {

            // there are two versions of each image loaded, the thumbnail and the full sized 
            // full sized images are loaded then hidden with css so the image is available to be swapped.
            // both images have id's that include the wp post id (the pid argument) - taht is how they are kept together
            //  the var declarations below use this shared wp-id to get the attributes from the full sized image
            alt = $("#display_"+pid).attr("alt");
            var src = $("#display_"+pid).attr("src");
            var w = $("#display_"+pid).attr("width");
            var h = $("#display_"+pid).attr("height");

            // if the image is portrait set the bg to black for appearence's sake
            if (parseInt(w) <= 670) {
                bgcolor = "#000";
            } else{
                bgcolor  = "#fff";
            }

            // shows the src url of the full sized  which is valid.
            console.log(src);

            // switch the bg color based upon image dimensions
            $("#gallery-focus").css("background-color", bgcolor);

            //swap out the main image - everything works except the src.
            $("#main-photo").attr("src", src);
            $("#main-photo").attr("width", w);
            $("#main-photo").attr("height", h);
        } else {
            //video galleries - working fine.
            alt = $("#image_"+pid).children("img").attr("alt");
            $("#gallery-focus").html($("#embed_"+pid).html());
        }

        $("#main-caption").text(alt);
    }
};
```

Other than that I don't see anything really wrong with the code. Do you have any console error?

Comment: I added the console statement for the demo I prob forgot the colon, the rest is styling issues - prob me being lazy (but alt can have multiple sources based on gallery type). The console throws no errors at all. Thanks Edit: I saw you work in WP dev - would there be any thing going from 3.x to 4.1 (js includes etc?)

Comment: Well quite a lot has changed from 3.x to 4.1 version, but I don't think that anything that would impact javascript changed. Try with pure javascript `document.getElementById("main-photo").src = src;`

Comment: already did :/ no luck. I am wondering if it is the responsive images srcset that is the issue - looking into that now. (this site was built non-responsive in early '13).

Comment: yes, that was it _ I had to eliminate the srcset being added to wp image tags - thanks for your help on this - good advice with js args.

Comment: No problem, glad you figured it out :)